# Backbone pushstate history not working

Tags: backbone.js, browser-history, pushstate, backbone-routing

I am using backbone.js routes and i am struggling to make history to work. Here is the code i have:

```
$(function() {  

    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
           "/": "initHome",
           "home": "initHome",
           "projects": "initProjects",
           "project/:id" : "initProject"
        }
    });

    // Instantiate the router
    var app_router = new AppRouter;

    app_router.on('route:initProject', function (id) {
        // Note the variable in the route definition being passed in here
          getContent("project",id);
    });

    app_router.on('route:initProjects', function () {
          getContent("projects");
    });

    app_router.on('route:initHome', function () {
          getContent("home");
    });


    // SINGLE PAGE MAGIC
    $(document).on("click",".links",function(e) {
        var href = $(this).attr("href");
        var url =  lang + "/" + href;    
            page = $(this).attr("data-id");
        var param = $(this).attr("data-param");         
        if (typeof(param) == 'undefined') { param = ""; }  

        if(activepage != href && !main.hasClass("loadingPage")){    
            loader.show();  
            firstInit = false;
            activepage = href;
            res = app_router.navigate(url, true);
            getContent(page,param);
        }   
        return false;                           
    });

    Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root: "/karlin/"});

});
```

Push state is working fine on click, but it wont call getContent() function when i try back/next buttons in the browser. I am an newbie to backbone, so any advice will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Change this: `res = app_router.navigate(url, true);`

To this: `app_router.navigate(url, {trigger: true});`

I can't see any reason to create a variable "res".

IMHO you've got a convoluted implementation of Backbone. I'd suggest moving your routes to the constructor like so:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
       "/": "initHome",
       "home": "initHome",
       "projects": "initProjects",
       "project/:id" : "initProject"
    },

    initProject: function (id) {
    // Note the variable in the route definition being passed in here
      getContent("project", id);
    },

    initProjects: function () {
      getContent("projects");
    },

    initHome: function () {
      getContent("home");
    }
});

// Instantiate the router
var app_router = new AppRouter;
```

Also, if you set up your routes properly like in the Backbone docs,

```
routes: {
  "help":                 "help",    // #help
  "search/:query":        "search",  // #search/kiwis
  "search/:query/p:page": "search"   // #search/kiwis/p7
},
```

you can pass parameters to the routes with traditional links. You can also move your if activePage statement to the router as a helper function for changing pages.

Router.navigate is for rare instances.

I suggest, reading the Backbone docs over and over. I learn something new every time. There's a lot there and Backbone is doing things efficiently already. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I second Andrew's answer: your use of routing is a bit odd.

If you're interested in learning more about why, as Andrew says, "Router.navigate is for rare instances", read pages 32-46 here: http://samples.leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction-sample.pdf

It's part of the sample for my book on Backbone.Marionette.js, but routing concepts remain the same. In particular, you'll learn why the default `trigger` value is `false`, and why designing your app routing with that in mind will make your apps better.